# How to update the column value of the table in an efficient way?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

I have a table with 30851204 rows and I want to update the value of one of its column and I am looking for an efficient way, like updating the value of entire column with following code. Instead of reading each value and update its value in the table

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 1
```

The column values take this general form:

```
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0zzzr2k>
```

I want to update each such value to be only the last segment pf the URL path, so just `m.0zzzr2k` in the above example.  The following Java code computes the desired value, but I do not know how to write an equivalent in MySQL.

```
String str[]= typ.split("<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns");
typ=str[1].substring(0, (str[1].length()-1));
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for.  Are you trying to write a program whose sole purpose is to make the change you describe?  Are you trying to add a feature to an existing program?  I guess you want a Java answer, but the context is unclear.

Comment: The description of what you are trying to do with the values of a column is difficult to understand. So from the linked file, are you just removing one specific character?

Comment: @jso, after pondering the question for a while, I *think* he wants to remove everything but the last path segment from each value.

Comment: @jso I want to remove this part ** <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns** of the value of the column which is ** <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0zzzr2k>**

Comment: @JohnBollinger exactlly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To update the column value of the table to achieve the desire result the following MySQL commands are needed.

`Update mytable SET column2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(right(column2,11), '>', 1);`

Answer (score 3):

Updating the column with SQL instead of Java will be more efficient as you seem to realise.

Depending on the pattern of the values stored in the column that you want to update, a solution might be as simple as using MySQL's [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_right) string function to grab the last *n* characters in the column:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = RIGHT(column1, 9)
```

This should work if you want to extract the same number of characters for all rows... depends on your data.

Or, if you always want the last part of the string following the last `/` you could use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, '/', -1)
```

Again, this depends on your data format.

Regular expressions are also supported, but there is no point in me trying to guess an appropriate pattern without fully knowing your data format.

Comment: Thanks, the commend that I need is `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(right('<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0zzzr2k>',11), '>', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`typ = typ.substring(typ.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);`